# How to better rewrite this repeat function

Tags: c#-3.0, refactoring

I have the following function that takes a string as parameter and repeats it a number of times (also a parameter).  I feel like this is something that's already in the framework or at least could be done better.  Any suggestions?

```
private string chr(string s, int repeat)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
    {
        result += s;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: AngryHacker, the answer to your question depends on what you mean by "better".  You've written some concise code that works.  Would "better" mean that the code executes faster for very large values of `repeat`.  Would "better" mean that the code uses the least least amount of memory possible?  Would it mean that the code would be easier to read or conform to some notion of what code should look like?

Comment: Be sure to evaluate the _clever_ answers for maintainability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Functional programming-style approach:**
*(requires at least C# 3.0)*

```
static class StringRepetitionExtension
{
    public static string Times(this int count, string what)
    {
        return count > 0 ? string.Concat(what, (count-1).Times(what))
                         : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
3.Times("Foobar")   // returns "FoobarFoobarFoobar"
```

*(Certainly not the most efficient solution, and due to the recursion there's always the danger of stack overflow with unreasonably large values for `count`; but I nevertheless wanted to share a slightly different, easy-to-understand approach.)*

Comment: Accepted for its awesomeness and elegance, not for its efficiency.  For efficiency see Imre L's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The most important improvement you could make to your function is to give it a descriptive name.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a `StringBuilder` as currently you're potentially allocating and deallocating lots of strings:

```
private string chr(string s, int repeat)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
    {
        result.Append(s);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Or even better if the string is only a single character:

```
private string chr(char s, int repeat)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.Append(s, repeat);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not the most efficient, but concise:

.NET 4:

```
String.Join(String.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat(s, repeat));
```

.NET 3.0/3.5:

```
String.Join(String.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat(s, repeat).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

If your input is really a single character rather than a string, you could simply do this:

```
var someChar = 'f';
var repeat = 10;
var repeated = new String(someChar, repeat);
```

Otherwise, I dont' think there's much else to do aside from using `StringBuilder` instead of concatenation:

```
private string chr(string s, int repeat)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder(s.Length * repeat);
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
    {
        result.Append(s);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: why not `result.Append(s, 0, repeat)` instead of the `for` cycle

Answer (score 4):

```
private string chr (string s, int repeat) {
   string result = new String(' ', repeat).Replace(" ",  s);
   return result;
}
```

Comment: You are far too clever!  I don't know if I can use this though - the next guy who maintains the code will probably want to dismember me.

Answer (score 3):

```
return new System.Text.StringBuilder().Insert(0,"repeatme",count).ToString()
```

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't got any upvotes so far, as it's probably the most straightforward solution for relying on no cleverness apart from using what the BCL already offers. _@Imre L:_ You could add a link to the MSDN documentation page for `StringBuilder.Insert(Int32, String, Int32)`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62eb5xsf.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using StringBuilder if your repeat parameter is very large.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/14294-C-string-vs-StringBuilder/

Answer (score 1):

```
private string chr(string s, int repeat)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, repeat)
        .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, i) => sb.Append(s)).ToString();
}
```